# get parameters of thread function c

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

I am doing a program in C where there are some threads, the problem is when I want to receive parameters from the thread function.

The structure looks like this:

```
struct parametro
{
  int pl;
};
```

This is the thread function:

```
DWORD WINAPI hijo(void *);

DWORD WINAPI hijo(void *p) 
{
  struct parametro* params = (struct parametro*)p;
  printf("\nPosicion %d", params->pl);
}
```

And here's the code that creates the threads:

```
int i;
    for(i=0; i<32; i++)
    {
        struct parametro p;
        p.pl = i;
        hilo = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &hijo, &p, 0, NULL);
    }
```

and it returns this:

```
Posicion 3
Posicion 5
Posicion 9
Posicion 15
Posicion 19
Posicion 23
Posicion 27
Posicion 30
Posicion 1
Posicion 1
Posicion 1
Posicion 1
Posicion 1
Posicion 1
Posicion 1
Posicion 1
```

The output is different each time the code runs.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Standard problem. You are passing the *same* pointer to all the threads. The threads are not guaranteed to run at the time that `CreateThread` is called. So by the time they run it is non-determinate what the value of `p` is at that time. You need a seperate struct for each thread,

Comment: Also note that `p` is only valid within the `for` loop. As soon as that loop completes all the pointers passed to the threads become invalid.

Comment: thanks, so what i have to do to separate `structs`?

Comment: The usual way is to malloc() a struct instance for each thread.  The threads can free() them before termination, (assuming they explicitly terminate).

Comment: .. or you can make an inflexible mess with arrays of things.

Answer (score 1):

You can create thread specific variable, assign them values which can then be used. For example

```
struct parametro p[32];

int i;

    for(i=0; i<32; i++)
    {
        p[i].pl = i;
        hilo = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &hijo, &p[i], 0, NULL);
    }
```

This will ensure that each thread gets a specific instance of structure which is initialized to the required value.

Comment: @AitorRamosPajares - and what it receive ? you not exit from create functions *before* all child threads exit ? `hilo = CreateThread` this is error - you have handle leaks. need or just close handle or store every handle in separate place

Comment: @AitorRamosPajares - without your relevant current src code impossible say what is your error

Comment: yeah but is too code, but is a two process, one of them with 32 threads, this only do the code that I have writen, the other process doesnt interfere.

Comment: I'm not sure that `printf` is thread-safe.  Put the call to `printf` inside a critical section, or use `MessageBox` instead of `printf`.  It also isn't clear whether your program waits for the threads to exit before exiting itself.  You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: @HarryJohnston - `printf` is thread safe. it call actual code inside critical section - [example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0d088085-beff-4a32-b96f-a0a0266e258d/how-to-use-outputl?forum=vclanguage) actual code of course can some change from crt version, but call to `_lock_*`  at begin and `_unlock_*` at the end not changed. internally this lock/unlock enter/leave critical section

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, I have placed a `system("pause")` after second process `for`, looks like `for` end before whole threads are created.

Comment: but i ask you at begin - `you not exit from create functions before all child threads exit ? ` . if you exit from functions - all local variables (pointer to which you pass to another threads) become invalid. more exactly data here can be overwritten and any time. so you and must wait until all threads is finished or how minimum end use your local variables (say signal event). and system("pause") - this is not solution. you need wait **exactly** not random time

Comment: yes, this is a try, all threads will be in a infinte loop doing other things,
but I dont know why all threads are created before the for end...

Comment: in this case better allocate data blocks for thread in heap and free it already in every thread. not use local variable in function, which exit